# performance test wireless network using loadrunner

Tags: performance, testing, networking, wireless, loadrunner

We have a requirement to test a wireless network that will be deployed to 1000s of people. I am looking for a way to test it with loadrunner.

Can you suggest a good approach to test the wireless connection for "Concurrent open connection" and network speed when 1000s of users are connected to the wireless network and downloading data.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong tool.  You need a network tool to answer a network question because the items you need to sample the item under test (the network) need to be proven stable and scalable beyond the network under all conditions.   You also need t a tool with specific characteristics related to the use of other finite resources, DISK, CPU and RAM specifically.  User applications fail these prequalifiers.  I recommend the tool IxChariot from Ixia Communications.  It is also the tool used by the WiFi alliance for certification.

Network tools are simpler tools in many respects, as you will be testing data flows.  Network tools are also far simpler to setup with dual homes load generators, using a hard wired connection for test setup and control, with a different network under test, the wireless network.

http://www.ixiacom.com/products/ixchariot

And no, I don't sell it.

Comment: Thanks James. I looked around for a few other tools and looks like IPerf\JPerf might be a good tool.